# How To Access Page 2 of JSON Response

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, flickr

I have successfully made a call to FlickR using Retrofit, and the result is returning several pages.

However, it appears that my response.body() is only returning page 1. My thought was to iterate through all of the pages to obtain the results, but I am unsure of how to access the subsequent pages after 1:

```
        mRequestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mQuery = mSearchTerm.getText().toString();
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/")
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();


            ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<Flicker> call = apiInterface.getImages(mQuery);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<Flicker>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Flicker> call, Response<Flicker> response) {
                    Log.v("RESPONSE_CALLED", "ON_RESPONSE_CALLED");
                    String didItWork = String.valueOf(response.isSuccessful());
                    Log.v("SUCCESS?", didItWork);
                    Log.v("RESPONSE_CODE", String.valueOf(response.code()));
                    Flicker testResponse = response.body();
                    Log.v("RESPONSE_BODY", "response:" + testResponse);
                    String total = response.body().getPhotos().getTotal().toString();
                    Log.v("Total", total);
                    List<Photo> photoResults = response.body().getPhotos().getPhoto();
                    int numberOfPages = response.body().getPhotos().getPages();
                    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++) {
                        for (Photo photo : photoResults) {
                            if (photo.getUrl_m() != null) {
                                Log.v("PHOTO_URL:", photo.getUrl_m()
                                );
                            }
                        }


                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Flicker> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        }
    });

    mSearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent toSearch = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FlickRActivity.class);
            startActivity(toSearch);
        }
    });
```

API Interface

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=1c448390199c03a6f2d436c40defd90e&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&extras=url_m")
    Call<Flicker> getImages(@Query("text") String query);

}
```

Search results for "lebron james":

Comment: read the doc. you just have to add a `page` query parameter to your call.

Comment: also in the doc is the (per_page) setting (Number of photos to return per page. If this argument is omitted, it defaults to 100. The maximum allowed value is 500) -- that will get you 5 pages in one go  -- https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html